# How does the same-origin policy apply between browser tabs?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, same-origin-policy

Let's assume that we have 2 open tabs in a browser containing page **A (A.html, A.js)** into the first tab and page **B (B.html, B.js)** into the second tab and that page **A** and **B** have the same origin (scheme, domain, port).

1. Can A.js call a function from B.js?
2. Can A.js modify the DOM of page B.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can A.js call a function from B.js?

No, the javascript need to be defined on your current page

> Can A.js modify the DOM of page B.html?

Yes, but you need a reference AND have the same origin.

If page A have a reference to page B, it is possible for A to modify the DOM in B.

Page A can have a reference to page B if page A opened page B and saved the reference. Also page B can access page A via the opener property. You can open a new tab/page in javascript with the [following code](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) :

```
// Open a new window
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");

// Write some text in the new window
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");     

// Write some text in the window that created the new window            
myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
```

**Same Origin Policy Limitation**

The same origin policy limit what you can access. If the 2 pages are on different domains, you will not be able to access the `window.document` property to read or write. Here is a list of [what you can access when the other page is from a different domain.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Window)